# Show progress of a for loop after it was started

Tags: bash, for, job-control, progress-information

I started a `for` loop in an interactive `bash` session. For this question we can assume the loop was something like

```
for i in dir/*; do
    program "$i"
done > log
```

The command takes a lot longer than expected and still runs. How can I see the current progress of the running `for` loop.

**Non-Solutions:**

- Look at `log`.
  *Doesn't work because:* `program` is expected to run silently. You can think of `program` as a validator. If the loop completes without any output then I'm happy.
- Stop the loop. Add some kind of progress indication (for instance `echo "$i"`). Start the loop again.
  *Doesn't work because:* The loop already ran for hours. I don't want to throw away all the time and energy invested in the current run. I assume everything works fine. I'm just curious and want to know the current progress.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> then `set -x; fg`
  *Doesn't work because:* `bash` doesn't continue the loop when using `fg`. After `fg` only the current/next command inside the loop will run, then the loop exits. You can try it yourself using `for i in {1..200}; do printf '%s ' $i; /usr/bin/sleep 0.5; done`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wildcards as `dir/*` always expand in the same order. This feature together with the current value of `$i` can be used to show a progress information.

The current value of `$i` can be retrieved by looking at the processes running on your system. The [following command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/821837/6770384) prints the currently running instance of `program` and its arguments.

<sub>If there are multiple `program` processes you may want to use the `--parent ...` option for `pgrep` to only match processes started by the shell running the `for` loop you want to inspect.</sub>

```
ps -o args= -fp $(pgrep program)
```

Extract the value of `$i` manually, then get your progress using

```
a=(dir/*)
n=$(printf %s\\0 "${a[@]}" | grep -zFxnm1 'the exact value of $i' | cut -f1 -d:) 
echo "Progress: $n / ${#a[@]}"
```

This works under two assumptions

1. The content of `dir/` does not change while running the loop. If `program` creates, renames, or deletes files then the numbers are likely wrong.
2. Calling `program` starts a new process. If `program` is a `bash` function then there won't be a sub-process for `program`. If the function `function` itself calls another program that starts a new process then you can look for that sub-program. However, if `program` is a bash built-in (commands that are listed by `help`) or a pure bash function (one that uses only `bash` built-ins) then you are out of luck.

If you have problem 2 or your `for` loop has a different structure than the one in the question (for example `program < "$1"` or a very long loop body with many different programs) then you might be able to get some progress information from `lsof` by looking at the files opened by your current shell session or its child processes.

Comment: There's also the [`watch` utility](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/watch.1.html) that runs a given command repeatedly, showing the output. It might be useful here.